# mysqli_connect(): PHP was built without openssl extension, can't send password encrypted in C:\

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, openssl

**SYSTEM:**

I have Windows 10/x64, Apache24, MySQL 8.0, PHP 7.2.10

**PHP CODE:**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'test123', 'ninja_project');
if (!$conn) {echo "Connection error:" . mysqli_connect_error();}
```

**ERRORS:**

Warning: mysqli_connect(): PHP was built without openssl extension, can't send password encrypted in C:\Users\User\www\phptutorial\ninjapizza\index.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Users\User\www\phptutorial\ninjapizza\index.php on line 3
Connection error:Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

**I DID:**

1. Checked solution through same topics already discussed on stackoverflow, but **found nothing helpful in my case**.
2. Enabled openssl in php.ini **extension=openssl.dll**
3. Specified directory **extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"**
4. Checked openssl status through CMD '''php -i''' - **openssl support => enabled**
5. Checked openssl modul through CMD '''php -m''' - **got openssl in list**
6. Checked localhost/index.php - **openssl enabled**
7. Checked file php-cli.ini on my PC - **don't have one**
8. I tried to rename `$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost'` to `$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1'`. Doesn't work. Same problem.
9. Granted All privileges to User.

**QUESTIONS:**

What else I can do to eliminate this issue?
I have file named openssl.cnf in Apache24 with default configuration status. Maybe I should do something inside this file to solve the problem?
Please help!

Comment: Have you provided the correct privileges to the user?

Comment: Yes, I granted all privileges.